# storing ip address in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to store a users ip address into a mysql table under VARCHAR (39) but its storing as just this `"::1"`

i am using this code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'hewden1'; 
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)    
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)   
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

 $cname       = $_POST['cname'];
   $creg      = $_POST['creg'];  
   $address      = $_POST['address'];  
   $post      = $_POST['post'];  
   $contactn      = $_POST['contactn'];
   $contactt      = $_POST['contactt'];
   $email      = $_POST['email'];
   $vat     = $_POST['vat'];

    $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];


$sql="INSERT INTO supplier_registration (company_name, company_reg_number, company_address, company_postcode, contact_name, contact_number, contact_email, company_vat_number, date_time, user_ip)
VALUES ('$cname', '$creg', '$address', '$post', '$contactn', '$contactt', '$email', '$vat', NOW(), '$ipaddress')";$result = mysql_query($sql); 

if($result){

echo "jobs a gooden";

}else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

can someone please show me where i am going wrong thanks

Comment: `::1` is the "localhost" address for IPv6.  What's the problem?

Comment: Do not use mysql* methods. They are deprecated.

Comment: Execute this code: echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; and see if it out-puts ::1 or something else

Comment: `"::1"`, it is your local host as your app running in local machine.

Comment: not all mysql* methods are deprecated) only mysql_*

Comment: Wow, [Injection City](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)!

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution, change your `ip` column to `varbinary (16)` datatype and then store ips using the following:

```
$ip = bin2hex(inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

*Note: make sure your php version is up to date as `inet_pton()` is a new function.*

Comment: Why is this better than `VARCHAR (39)`?

Comment: Less data, don't need to store `.`

Comment: or you know.. An unsigned INT could keep the contents of `iner_pton`.

Comment: sql unsigned int is 32bit. ipv6 is 128bit. enjoy having all of your ipv6 addresses destroyed.

Comment: My (and OP's) localhost `::1` in IPv6 is becoming `00000000000000000000000000000001`, which isn't fitting into `varbinary(16)`.  Am I missing something?